# What is the jquery data parameter for php file upload in this example?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an html page with a  section that collects basic customer information:  email, first and last name, etc.  The form ends with a button for the end-user to click, and I'm using an onClick event to call a jquery script.  The jquery script calls a php file to send the data to the server.

For example:

```
function postData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url : 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST'
    });
}

function sendReply() {
    // autoresponder
}

postData().done(sendReply);
```

In some examples, I have seen a "data" parameter that would go in the postData function.  For example:

```
function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'your_url/ajax.php',
           data:{action:'call_this'},
      });
 }
```

My question is:  if I'm calling upload.php, will that automatically take the form data and process it in the php file, provded that the php file is coded correctly for form data upload (using $_POST['variable_name'];)?  In other words, is the data parameter in this jquery code irrelevant when I'm calling a php file with html  data?

I'm sorry if this question is very elementary, but I'm new to php and I've never done this before.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes, I read that but it doesn't answer my question.  This question is whether the data parameter is needed in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question, but if you're using AJAX and you want to send data to a php script then you NEED to specify the data you're sending as it won't be automatically sent or anything of that sort.

Comment: My issue here is that the docs specify how data is to be sent, but does that apply to a php file?  It looks like the data (converted by ajax to a query string) would be passed to the php file, but the docs are not specific to php.

Comment: If your PHP script needs any values set in the `$_POST` array, then the data is needed. It depends on the script and there's no right or wrong in general.

Comment: I'm looking at data: $('form').serialize() now.  That may do the job, and if so I'll post back.

Comment: Don't mix regular HTML form submission with AJAX calls. Either one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: I don't do that here.  I need jquery because it's a button click.  I've used this in other contexts, but not for form submission.